# How to cancel ClearCase deliver operation

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

So I'm trying to finish up some ClearCase work. I'm extremely new to Clearcase, keep that in mind - I've basically been stumbling through this somehow making it work until this point.

I'm using Clearcase Remote Client, and am trying to remove one of my views, but am getting the following error:

```
CRVAP0087E CCRC command 'rmview' failed: View path/to/int/view has a UCM deliver or rebase operation in progress.
Please complete or cancel the UCM operation before removing this view.
```

I tried ignoring this, but then when I try delivering the other view that I made after encountering errors with this one, I get this error:

```
Unable to prepare the integration view "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int" for deliver: error detected by ClearCase subsystem

ClearCase CM Server: Error: View "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int" is set activity to activity
"deliver.bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_2.20150929.122347" which is currently involved in an
active deliver or rebase operation.  The set activity of this view may not be
changed until the operation has completed.
ClearCase CM Server: Error: Resume, complete or cancel the operation in progress in view "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int".
View "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int" cannot be used in the current deliver operation.
ClearCase CM Server: Error: Unable to prepare view common.
Unable to prepare the integration view "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int" for deliver: error detected by ClearCase subsystem

ClearCase CM Server: Error: View "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int" is set activity to activity
"deliver.bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_2.20150929.122347" which is currently involved in an
active deliver or rebase operation.  The set activity of this view may not be
changed until the operation has completed.
ClearCase CM Server: Error: Resume, complete or cancel the operation in progress in view "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int".
View "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int" cannot be used in the current deliver operation.
ClearCase CM Server: Error: Unable to prepare view common.
```

So it seems that when I was running into all these delivery errors prior to starting this delivery, it really messed something up. But, I'm not sure what got messed up or how to remedy this situation, as I said, I'm extremely new to Clearcase and have been just barely stumbling through this.

I'm not using any sort of console to do this, and I'm very limited in what I can actually use -- I think the remote client is all I'm given access to in order to do all this, so it would be great if I could fix this in the remote client somehow.

Comment: Would https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014777493#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014780694 help? What version of ClearCase and CCRC are you using? (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205485 reports an old bug)

Answer (score 1):

Some details are missing from your question, but here's my interpretation:

The first problem is you're trying to remove a view (path/to/int/view) which is involved in a deliver or rebase. You ignored the error and made a different view (presumably source view) and tried another deliver, which is also returning the error:

```
Unable to prepare the integration view "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int" 
for deliver: error detected by ClearCase subsystem

ClearCase CM Server: Error: View "bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_int" is set to activity
deliver.bluhman_iOSTablet_6.4.2_2.20150929.122347"
which is currently involved in an active deliver or rebase operation.
```

My guess is you are using the same target view as the original deliver. The best recourse seeing as the existing deliver is still in progress from the first view is to resume that deliver op from that view to the same target,  or undo it.

If using GUI, it should detect the deliver in progress and prompt you to resume/cancel (Undo). If using the [command line](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-6), 
`cleartool deliver -cancel -stream ...`. You can also use `clear deliver -status -stream ...` to get the status.

Once the deliver has been canceled or completed you will be able to remove the view.